# Что такое салки?

Tags: этимология

Есть детская игра салки. Насколько я знаю, там нужно друг друга догонять. А что это за слово такое? Почему игра так называется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Салки - от "салить", мазать салом. В игре мажут не салом, а просто касаются рукой. Это называтся "осалить". Осаленный становится водящим - и сам старается осалить кого-то из играющих, остальные от него убегают.